# PostgreSQL transform IN operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 13.2. Create view using CASE and IN operator like this:

```
create or replace view pay.test as
select
      (case when name in ('a', 'b', 'c') then 1 else 0 end)::bool isInType
from pay.FasetItems
```

But when i see this view in pgAdmin (chose my view in Browser-View then SQL tab):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW pay.test
 AS
 SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN fasetitems.name::text = ANY (ARRAY['a'::character varying, 'b'::character varying, 'c'::character varying]::text[]) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END::boolean AS isintype
   FROM pay.fasetitems;
```

Why IN operator transform in ANY and text array? How prevent this transformation? I prefer version with IN operator

Comment: Can you give a very good reason why you prefer something? Does it make the query better, or perform different?

Comment: It's an implementation detail, you cannot change this. The `IN` operator is implemented this way. However, you can change the unnecessary complex `case` expression to much simpler `name = any('{a, b, c}')`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent that transformation. PostgreSQL doesn't store view definitions in text form, but as a binary parse tree. When you retrieve the view definition from the database, that parse tree is translated back into an SQL statement (this is also why you lose all formatting). Now `IN (1, 2, 3)` is internally converted to `= ANY ('{1,2,3}')`, so you don't have much choice there.

If you need to preserve the original view definition, use a source versioning system.